# Android InAPP-purchase V3 not return more than 16 item

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have a Android application with inapp-purchase feature. My application have 150 purchase item. I use IInAppBillingService for getting details of a list of SKUs.

My sample code here:

```
ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < productId.length; i++) {
    skuList.add(productId[i]);
}
Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
querySkus.putStringArrayList(GET_SKU_DETAILS_ITEM_LIST, skuList);
try {
    return mService.getSkuDetails(VERSION, mContext.getPackageName(),
            ITEM_TYPE_INAPP, querySkus);
} catch (RemoteException e) {
    LogUtils.e(TAG, String.valueOf(e.getMessage()));
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If my productId.length return under 16 item, I got all my purchase item. It return empty list if I try more than 16 item. I don't know why. Anybody have the same problem with me?

- I checked the name of the productId.
- I re-ordered the product list.
- I print out logcat.

=> But I can't find any way to fix that.